# Returning values via an Observable to a caller

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have a class with the following method which returns an `Observable`:

```
public Observable<JsonObject> doSend(String message) {
   CompletableFuture<JsonObject> resp = this.send(message);

   return Observable.fromFuture(resp.whenComplete((response, err) -> {
      response.success(callback -> {
         return;
      });
      return ;
}));
```

The method is called from the following method of another class, where `senderClass` is an instance of the class which contains the above method.

```
private void getData(Message<JsonObject> msgHandler) {
   Observable<JsonObject> o = senderClass.doSend(...);
      o.doOnComplete(() -> {
        // do something
   });

   o.doOnEach(onNotification -> {
      onNotification.getError();
   });
}
```

When the method `doSend` on the first class is called, the `response` parameter in the handler correctly contains the result of the call to the `send` message in the same class. The issue is that the value does not appear to be returned, and therefore cannot be accessed in the second class from the Observable which is returned from the `doSend` method.

What is the correct way to write this so that the value can be set in the first class and accessed in the second?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable` (along with the other reactive types) is designed with a fluent interface in which each invocation returns a new instance enhanced with the declared behavior.

to illustrate the point, this:

```
Observable<Object> o = newObservable();
o.doOnComplete(...);
o.doOnEach(...);
```

...is not the same as this:

```
Observable<Object> o = newObservable()
    .doOnComplete(...)
    .doOnEach(...);
```

in the former snippet, the calls to `doOnComplete()` and `doOnEach` create a new instance of `Observable`, but since they are not assigned to a handler they are simply discarded without `o` being enhanced with those behaviors. in other words - those methods do not mutate their receiver.

the latter example is the idiomatic approach. `o` in this case is the accumulated result of applying the behaviors supplied to `doOnComplete()` and `doOnEach` to the originally constructed stream.

try updating `getData()` using the second approach and see if that resolves your issue.

also, i think `doSend()` can be simplified as:

```
Observable.fromFuture(this.send(message))
```

...unless of course you've got some other logic there that you've chosen to omit.

Comment: Thanks, but even when calling doOnComplete, doOnEach, and flatMap on the the Observable itself as you point out, those methods are not called. I can see from the debugger that observable.source.future.result.data  has been set  correctly by the CompletableFuture used to construct the observable, but cannot figure out the correct way to access it.